# Add rownum from specific number - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
col1 col2
1    a
1    b
1    c
```

I want to add rownum but from a specific number, for ex. starting from 100, so it would look like:

```
col1 col2 rn
1    a    100
1    b    101
1    c    102
```

I know how to add rownum like below:

```
select a.*, rownum as rn from table1 a;
```

But I don't know how to add from a specific number. How to do it in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI SQL way of doing this would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 99 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) rn
FROM table1;
```

You might be able to use Oracle's `ROWNUM` function here, but in that case you would also need to provide an `ORDER BY` clause to your query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 99 + ROWNUM AS rn
FROM table1
ORDER BY col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not necessary to get this kind of rownum from systematic source, you can use below query for example

```
select a.*, 99+rownum as rn from table1 a;
```